# Typeclasses with multiple fields vs. single field in Coq / Unexpected behaviour of Compute command

Tags: coq, typeclass

I'm studying typeclasses in Coq with the book Software Foundations.

Running the following:

```
Class Eq A :=
{
eqb: A -> A -> bool;
}.

Notation "x =? y" := (eqb x y) (at level 70).

Instance eqBool : Eq bool :=
{
eqb := fun (b c : bool) => 
   match b, c with
     | true, true => true
     | true, false => false
     | false, true => false
     | false, false => true
   end
}.

Compute (true =? false).
```

I get the message `= false : bool`, as expected.
But if I do the following instead,

```
Class Eq A :=
{
eqb: A -> A -> bool;
eqb_refl: forall (x : A), eqb x x = true;
}.

Notation "x =? y" := (eqb x y) (at level 70).

Instance eqBool : Eq bool :=
{
eqb := fun (b c : bool) => 
   match b, c with
     | true, true => true
     | true, false => false
     | false, true => false
     | false, false => true
   end
}.
Proof.
  intros []; reflexivity.
Qed.

Compute (true =? false).
```

I get the message `= (let (eqb, _) := eqBool in eqb) true false : bool`.
I don't seem to be able to simplify this expression and not sure what went wrong and where.
How can I define the typeclass above with the extra hypothesis, and still be able to use the instance i've defined (i.e get the same message as before)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Qed` command creates opaque definitions, which are never unfolded by commands like `Compute`.  You can tell Coq to make only the proof obligation opaque by using the `Program Instance` command:

```
Require Import Coq.Program.Tactics.

Class Eq A :=
{
eqb: A -> A -> bool;
eqb_refl: forall (x : A), eqb x x = true;
}.

Notation "x =? y" := (eqb x y) (at level 70).

Program Instance eqBool : Eq bool :=
{
eqb := fun (b c : bool) =>
   match b, c with
     | true, true => true
     | true, false => false
     | false, true => false
     | false, false => true
   end
}.
Next Obligation. now destruct x. Qed.

Compute (true =? false).
```

Comment: Yet another way would be to reuse the existing functions and proofs about them: `From Coq Require Import Bool.
    Instance eqBool : Eq bool :=
    {
      eqb := eqb;
      eqb_refl := eqb_reflx
    }.`